# Which UI library do you think is lightweight and easy to customize for web development?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dojo

I am looking for a good UI library for web development. I expected it to be lightweight which means that it should not generate too much dom structure and also easy to customizable. I have tried dijit but it is too complicated.

Besides, another concern is it seems that all the UI library is based on the core library, for example, dijit is based on dojo, jquery-ui is based on jquery. If I choose one core library, it seems it would be not a good idea to choose another type ui library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would it seem that a UI library based on a core library isn't a good idea? That's a pretty good example of modularity.

At the moment, I'm pretty sure that jQuery wins. Really, the learning curve is *super* low and there's a huge community for it.

My own experiences with jQuery have been great so far. Ripping off scripts (either global modular stuff or widget-specific) is a breeze and generally, if you can think of something that you want to do with it that's not in the core lib, someone's already created a plugin for it.

As for the UI element, the UI lib is great and recently I've been developing with the theme roller framework, which makes skinning/theming *rediculously* easy.

/2cents